# Create object in aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have this result after group by UserId with Aggregation Framework. I want create a single Document with "merge" array foo and ability

My Aggregation

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "userId" : ObjectId("53bab268ceee750615240269")
            },
            "foo" : [ 
                "0.109", 
                "0.105", 
                "0.50", 
                "0.1", 
                "foo"
            ],
            "ability" : [ 
                "Power", 
                "Energy", 
                "ReactiveEnergy", 
                "Stamina", 
                "bar"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I like to have

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "userId" : ObjectId("53bab268ceee750615240269")
            },
            "fooFinal" : [ 
                {"0.109",power} 
                {"0.105",Energy }
                {"0.50",ReactiveEnergy }
                {"0.1",Stamina }
                {"foo",bar}
            ],
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I want to use like similar $each, but i can't use it inside aggregate

Comment: That would not be a valid structure for the result. Do you actually mean just getting those values under different keys or as arrays of the "pairs"?

Comment: Additionally, it would **really** help to have some idea of the structure of the original documents you are getting this result from. All you have posted is what your aggregation result currently is and what you want to get ( with an invalid structure ). It helps to know where you are coming "from" as a source document and also what you are currently doing, as in your current aggregation operation.

Comment: As at MongoDB 2.6, there is no array indexing operator in the Aggregation Framework so I'm not sure how you would combine the two arrays. It would definitely be helpful to see what document format you started with as there may be an easier way to make the transformation. I would also suggest upvoting/watching [SERVER-4589](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker, which is the feature request for an array indexing operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do This in your $group

```
 $group:{
    _id:{'userId':'$userId'},
    'fooFinal' : {$push:{
        foo:'$foo',
        ability:'$ability'}
    }
}
```