# MongoDB: Create Object in Aggregation result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to return Object as a field in my Aggregation result similar to the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674163/create-object-in-aggregation) question. However in the solution mentioned above, the Aggregation results in an Array of Objects with just one item in that array, not a standalone Object. For example, a query like the following with a `$push` operation

```
 $group:{
     _id: "$publisherId",
     'values' : { $push:{
         newCount: { $sum: "$newField" },
         oldCount: { $sum: "$oldField" } }
     }
}
```

returns a result like this

```
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "values" : [ 
            {
                "newCount" : 100, 
                "oldCount" : 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

not one like this

```
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "values" : {
                "newCount" : 100, 
                "oldCount" : 200
         }
    }
}
```

The latter is the result that I require. So how do I rewrite the query to get a result like that? Is it possible or is the former result the best I can get?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** operator, just add a final **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that will create the embedded document. Follow this guideline:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$publisherId",      
            "newCount": { "$sum": "$newField" },
            "oldCount": { "$sum": "$oldField" } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" {
            "values": {
                "newCount": "$newCount",
                "oldCount": "$oldCount"
            }
        }       
    }   
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```